# In .NET what is a way to test an Async Lock, proving that reentrancy is prevented?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await, reentrancy

Say I have a method like this that I wish to test:

```
public async Task ConnectAsync()
{
    using (await _connectMutex.LockAsync())
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

I'm not interested in testing the lock directly (I trust that the developer of the [AsyncLock](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) knew what he was doing). Instead, what I wanted to demonstrate/prove was that if I hit this method with 3 threads simultaneously, that the total test execution time will be >= 3 seconds. My question is simply: how would one arrange such a test?

Comment: Why are you trying to test a mutex? What is `_connectMutex`? Its usually up to the developer of that type to test it, I would just trust that it works correctly, kind of like saying "how do I test `string.Length`", really you shouldn't have to.

Comment: @RonBeyer Not every developer in the world is infallable.  Sometimes code that people besides you write has bugs in it.

Comment: @Servy 100% agree, if this were code that were pulled off of GitHub that did not include any kind of unit tests, then by all means write a test for it, but if its part of a known framework from a trusted group (like MS, and nothing says it isn't a built-in mutex) then I wouldn't waste time trying to test it, unless you are trying to reproduce a bug. If you want to ship code, you have to pick/choose the battles, this is one I'd choose not to unless something gave me a reason to do it (bug).

Comment: @RonBeyer It' not like this is a framework type.  It's a 3rd party type.  *I* would trust it, but then again I'm very familiar with Steven's work.  For someone else who may reasonably have insufficient reason to trust Steven on faith, writing some tests for his library would be entirely reasonable.  Of course, whether or not its worth it also depends on the project; different projects have different demands for how confident they need to be in correctness.  When you're writing the code for a pacemaker, and people's lives are literally in your hands, you might write a few extra test cases.

Comment: @Servy I missed that the OP had updated the post between my first comment and the last one to include information on this being 3rd party (I originally thought it was built-in). Depending on the use-case, yes, it is reasonable to write a test for this, personally I'd fork it and write dedicated tests outside of whatever integration project it was going into.  That way it can be pushed back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your asynchronous lock has semantics such that the lock is granted synchronously if it is available (which is a reasonable assumption), then you can test it as such:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PreventsReentrancy()
{
  var mutex = ...;
  var firstLock = mutex.LockAsync();
  var secondLock = mutex.LockAsync();

  Assert.IsTrue(firstLock.IsCompleted);
  Assert.IsFalse(secondLock.IsCompleted);
}
```

**Edit for updated question:**

> what I wanted to demonstrate/prove was that if I hit this method with 3 threads simultaneously, that the total test execution time will be >= 3 seconds. My question is simply: how would one arrange such a test?

First, I'd double-check that that's *really* what you want to test. Since this is my `AsyncLock`, I can say that there are unit tests already verifying mutual exclusion and preventing reentrant locks. I really, strongly avoid unit testing anything time related.

But if you *actually* want to do a unit test with a time requirement, I would recommend first hooking the `Task.Delay` method (e.g., using Microsoft Fakes) and replacing it with an implementation that uses Rx's `IScheduler` instead of a timer. Then you can use Rx's `TestScheduler` to verify the timing behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't test the lock using the method around it. If you want to test the lock test the lock directly:

```
public async Task TestAsync()
{
    using (await _connectMutex.LockAsync())
    using (await _connectMutex.LockAsync())
}
```

That's assuming this is your lock implementation. If it's an external one leave it to the developer, otherwise you'll need to test **everything**.